# Authentification test with behat, username not found

Tags: php, selenium-chromedriver, behat, mink

I have a problem with my login test using behat,mink and selenium
I got the error

```
Form field with id|name|label|value "username" not found.
```

My scenario :

```
@javascript
Scenario: View users list
Given I am on "http://localhost/admin"
Then I wait 60 seconds
And And I am authenticated as "admin" using "admin"
Then I should see "List of customers"
```

My FeatureContext.php:

```
/**
 * @Then /^I wait (\d+) seconds$/
 */
public function iWaitSeconds($seconds)
{
    sleep($seconds);
}
/**
 * @Given /^And I am authenticated as "([^"]*)" using "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function andIAmAuthenticatedAsUsing($username, $password) {
    $this->visit('http://localhost/admin');
    $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('css','input[name="username"]')->setValue($username);
    $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('css','input[name="password"]')->setValue($password);
    $this->pressButton('Login');
}
```

My behat.yml:

```
default:
extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
        base_url: http:localhost/admin
        browser_name: chrome
        javascript_session: selenium2
        selenium2:
            browser: chrome
        goutte: ~
paths:
    features:  features
    bootstrap: features/bootstrap
```

I can't understand why this error because I have a form with this name : "username". Please help me. Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Why do you need another `And` for this line `And And I am authenticated as "admin" using "admin"`? It doesn't like right!
2. Is your login form inside `http://localhost/admin` or something like `http://localhost/admin/login`?
3. You say `Given I am on "http://localhost/admin"` in your Gherkin and then  call `$this->visit('http://localhost/admin');` in your FeatureContext. Why?
4. I use these for my case if it helps:

**Version 1)**

```
/**
 * @Given /^I am logged in$/
 * @Given /^I am logged in as "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iAmLoggedIn($username = 'user')
{
    $this->visit('/logout');
    $this->visit('/login');
    $this->fillField('username', $username);
    $this->fillField('password', 'password');
    $this->pressButton('_submit');
}
```

**Version 2)**

```
use Behat\Behat\Context\Step;

/**
 * @When /^I log in as "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iLogInAs($username)
{
    return [
        new Step\Given('I am not logged in'),
        new Step\When('I go to "/login"'),
        new Step\When('I fill in "username" with "'.$username.'"'),
        new Step\When('I fill in "password" with "password"'),
        new Step\Then('I press "_submit"'),
        new Step\Then('I should be on "/welcome"'),
    ];
}
```

**EDIT:**

Place `Then I wait 60 seconds` after `Given I am on "http://localhost/admin"` step. Run your tests (in browser mode) so that you can visually verify if you're in where the login page is.

```
/**
 * @Given /^I wait (\d+) seconds$/
 */
public function iWaitSeconds($seconds)
{
    sleep($seconds);
}
```

**Example behat.yml**

```
default:
    context:
        class: Site\FrontendBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext
        parameters:
            output_path: %behat.paths.base%/build/behat/output/
            screen_shot_path: %behat.paths.base%/build/behat/screenshot/
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension:
            mink_driver: true
            kernel:
                env: test
                debug: true
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            base_url: 'http://localhost/myproject/web/app_test.php/'
            files_path: %behat.paths.base%/build/dummy/
            javascript_session: selenium2
            browser_name: firefox
            goutte: ~
            selenium2: ~
    paths:
        features: %behat.paths.base%/src
        bootstrap: %behat.paths.features%/Context

# Add "-p firefox" parameter to behat command to run tests with Firefox browser
firefox:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            browser_name: firefox
```

Comment: I get the same error, I tried: $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('css','input[name="username"]')->setValue($username); but I get another error : 
Call to a member function setValue() on a non object

Comment: Sound like you're not in correct page or the the name of the field is wrong. See edit note above. I updated the answer.

Comment: Does your test open browser window? If so do you see the login form?

Comment: I edited my question, yes I see the login form and I got the error:
"Call to a member function setValue() on a non object"

Comment: When running the test, do you see the element in page source code? As I described in EDIT above, you need to add `sleep()` to give yourself a chance to right click and open source code though.

Comment: Don't need this function because browser doesn't close

Comment: I edited the question, I added sleep() but I get the same error

Comment: Turn `http://localhost/admin` into `http://localhost/` in `behat.yml` and also remove `http://localhost` bit from your Gherkin and FeatureContext to leave only `/admin` or `admin`. Try something like these.

Answer (score -1):

The error was that : I had to delete :

```
$this->visit('http://localhost/admin');
```

And now without this line it works

Comment: Well if you dictate behat by saying "my base_url is admin section of the site" which is technically wrong approach and it should be without admin part. You're just hiding underlying problem with this solution! You should apply what I said in my last comment above.